# RegEx: Grabbing values before the first dash, and anything after the second dash

Tags: regex

I have a value like this:

```
cal-hinderson-sin-trl
tn-hiker-tim-gies
```

What regex will return the values enclosed in the first and second dashes (e.g. hinderson and any other value)?

More examples

```
he-tacks limb-exsf-as
```

In this case I'm looking for "tacks limb".

```
ntf-browndog-as-idk
```

In this case I'm looking for "browndog"

Comment: Is `cal-hinderson-sin-trl
tn-hiker-tim-gies` a single, two-line value? If so, what do you want to extract from it: only `hinderson`, or also `hiker`?

Answer (score 0):

Considering it's the first match in the string, you should be able to simply use this regex, if you can use look-arounds.

```
(?<=-)\w+(?=-)
```

Or, less pretty:

```
^\w+-(\w+)-.*$
```

This last one makes sure that there's only one sequence of word characters, followed by a dash which is then followed by the group you want to capture.

Comment: The `^\w+-(\w+)-.*$` returns just first entry. `hinderson` in `cal-hinderson-sin-trl` string. So it doesnt work as expected.

Comment: @misterion Are you sure that that's the expected behaviour? *What regex will return the values enclosed in the first and second dashes* I read that as "return the value between the first two dashes.

Answer (score 0):

The first and seconds groups has values enclosed in the first and second dashes:

```
\w+-(\w+)-(\w+)-\w+
```